# how to clear 10013 error message and access port number 80

Tags: python, windows, sockets, http, client-server

```
from socket import *
import socket
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8000
serversocket.bind((host, 80))
serversocket.listen(5)
while True:
    print "Server is ready to listen!" 
    c, addr = serversocket.accept()
    y = c.recv(1024)
    print y
serversocket.close()
```

> File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
>       return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions

I tried shutting down the windows defender, running cmd as admin, blocking firewall. It works completely fine with other port numbers.

Comment: I have created a simple client just to check if I can connect to the port no 80, but it says **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 6, in <module>
    serversocket.bind((host, 80))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions**
I tried shutting down the windows defender, running cmd as admin, blocking firewall. It works completely fine with other port numbers.

Comment: I would suggest you to disable antivirus software and Firewall together (as a test) on the computer temporarily and try connecting and check if it works.

Comment: Try to start program with superuser rights or try to change port. Check if port 80 is not used by another process

Comment: It is used by TCP and I can't kill it. system and compressed memory

Comment: CAN'T KILL SYSTEM PROCESS WHICH IS USING 80